# Coordinate Transformation in Mass-Pulley Problems

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

[image]

Let's say we want to determine the tension $T$ of the rope in the setup above.

For the mass $m_1$, in $XOY$ coordinate system, Newton's 2nd law yields 
$$m_1 a_1 \, \hat{x} = T \, \hat{x} - m_1 g \sin(\theta) \, \hat{x}$$

For the mass $m_2$, in $X'O'Y'$ coordinate system, Newton's 2nd law yields 
$$-m_2 a_2 \, \hat{y}' = T \, \hat{y}' - m_2 g  \, \hat{y}'$$

Now if I want to solve these equations for T, then I will need to do the coordinate transformation to express, say, the eq. for $m_2$ in terms of the unite vectors $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$. Here, $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ are the unit vectors of the $XOY$ coordinate system.

Usually in textbooks, the problem is solved in the following way. At first the two equations are written in the following way:

$$m_1 a_1 = T - m_1 g \sin(\theta)$$, $$-m_2 a_2 = T - m_2 g$$ and, then solve them for $a_1 = a_2 \equiv a$ and $T$.

**Question**

How this approach is mathematically justified when the first two equations are written for two different coordinate systems and we just don't bother to use any coordinate transformation?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I have edited it.